# How to make elementor form validation occur after i left the input?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, forms, elementor

I'm making a form that shows when the answer is not valid or is valid, as in the examples:
[invalid answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YM5M.png) and [valid answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBW7g.png)

This part itself is ready. The problem is that the form is invalid by default, i would like form validation to occur only when I leave the field and stay normal like the example: [default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46k4x.png)

The only code I thought could help me was this:

```
    input:not(:focus):invalid + .elementor-field-label {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(0px, -24px);
}
```

*But it didn't work and the form is still invalid by default.*

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-field-group input:not([type="checkbox"])').forEach((e) => {
  e.parentNode.insertBefore(e, e.previousElementSibling);
})
```

```css
/*Rótulo do formulário*/
.elementor-field-label {
    z-index: 1;
    /*Cor do fundo do rótulo (Só funciona com background sólido)*/
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    /*Distância da borda (Na ordem = top, right e bottom)*/
    margin: 0 20px;
    /*Tamanho da caixa*/
    padding: 4px !important;
    cursor: text !important;
    /*100ms = 0,1s de velocidade da animação*/
    /*ease-out é um tipo de animação rápida no início e lento no final*/
    transition: font-size 150ms ease-out, -webkit-transform 150ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 150ms ease-out, font-size 150ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 150ms ease-out, font-size 150ms ease-out,
    -webkit-transform 150ms ease-out;
    /*Tamanho da fonte do rótulo*/
    font-size: 14px;
}

    input:focus + .elementor-field-label {
    /*Borda (Na ordem = largura, tipo de borda e cor)*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(0px, -24px);
    transition: background-color .3s;
    transition: border-color .3s;
}

    input:valid + .elementor-field-label {
    /*Borda (Na ordem = largura, tipo de borda e cor)*/
    border: 1px solid lime;
    background-color: lime;
    color: black !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(0px, -24px);

}

    input:not(:focus):invalid + .elementor-field-label {
    /*Borda (Na ordem = largura, tipo de borda e cor)*/
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(0px, -24px);
}
 
    input:invalid{
        border-color: red !important;
}

    input:focus{
        border-color: black !important;
}
    
    input:valid{
        border-color: lime !important;
}


**Note**:It's an elementor form widget, cannot be faithfully reproduced by code that i don't know, that was the best I could do.
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-0f96ee3 e-con-boxed e-con" data-id="0f96ee3" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;,&quot;jet_parallax_layout_list&quot;:[],&quot;content_width&quot;:&quot;boxed&quot;}">
<div class="e-con-inner">
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-9e31afd elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="9e31afd" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
<style>/*! elementor - v3.8.1 - 13-11-2022 */
.elementor-heading-title{padding:0;margin:0;line-height:1}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title[class*=elementor-size-]>a{color:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-small{font-size:15px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-medium{font-size:19px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-large{font-size:29px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xl{font-size:39px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xxl{font-size:59px}</style><h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Texto aqui</h2> </div>
</div>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-e828415 elementor-widget__width-initial elementor-button-align-stretch elementor-widget elementor-widget-form" data-id="e828415" data-element_type="widget" data-settings="{&quot;step_next_label&quot;:&quot;Pr\u00f3ximo&quot;,&quot;step_previous_label&quot;:&quot;Anterior&quot;,&quot;button_width&quot;:&quot;100&quot;,&quot;step_type&quot;:&quot;number_text&quot;,&quot;step_icon_shape&quot;:&quot;circle&quot;}" data-widget_type="form.default">
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
<style>/*! elementor-pro - v3.8.2 - 21-11-2022 */
.elementor-button.elementor-hidden,.elementor-hidden{display:none}.e-form__step{width:100%}.e-form__step:not(.elementor-hidden){display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap}.e-form__buttons{-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap}.e-form__buttons,.e-form__buttons__wrapper{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}.e-form__indicators{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between;-ms-flex-wrap:nowrap;flex-wrap:nowrap;font-size:13px;margin-bottom:var(--e-form-steps-indicators-spacing)}.e-form__indicators,.e-form__indicators__indicator{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.e-form__indicators__indicator{-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;padding:0 var(--e-form-steps-divider-gap)}.e-form__indicators__indicator__progress{width:100%;position:relative;background-color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-progress-background-color);border-radius:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-progress-border-radius);overflow:hidden}.e-form__indicators__indicator__progress__meter{width:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-progress-meter-width,0);height:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-progress-height);line-height:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-progress-height);padding-right:15px;border-radius:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-progress-border-radius);background-color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-progress-color);color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-progress-meter-color);text-align:right;-webkit-transition:width .1s linear;-o-transition:width .1s linear;transition:width .1s linear}.e-form__indicators__indicator:first-child{padding-left:0}.e-form__indicators__indicator:last-child{padding-right:0}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-inactive{color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-inactive-primary-color,#c2cbd2)}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-inactive [class*=indicator--shape-]:not(.e-form__indicators__indicator--shape-none){background-color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-inactive-secondary-color,#fff)}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-inactive object,.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-inactive svg{fill:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-inactive-primary-color,#c2cbd2)}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-active{color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-active-primary-color,#39b54a);border-color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-active-secondary-color,#fff)}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-active [class*=indicator--shape-]:not(.e-form__indicators__indicator--shape-none){background-color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-active-secondary-color,#fff)}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-active object,.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-active svg{fill:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-active-primary-color,#39b54a)}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-completed{color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-completed-secondary-color,#fff)}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-completed [class*=indicator--shape-]:not(.e-form__indicators__indicator--shape-none){background-color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-completed-primary-color,#39b54a)}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-completed .e-form__indicators__indicator__label{color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-completed-primary-color,#39b54a)}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-completed .e-form__indicators__indicator--shape-none{color:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-completed-primary-color,#39b54a);background-color:initial}.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-completed object,.e-form__indicators__indicator--state-completed svg{fill:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-completed-secondary-color,#fff)}.e-form__indicators__indicator__icon{width:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-padding,30px);height:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-padding,30px);font-size:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-icon-size);border-width:1px;border-style:solid;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:10px}.e-form__indicators__indicator__icon img,.e-form__indicators__indicator__icon object,.e-form__indicators__indicator__icon svg{width:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-icon-size);height:auto}.e-form__indicators__indicator__icon .e-font-icon-svg{height:1em}.e-form__indicators__indicator__number{width:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-padding,30px);height:var(--e-form-steps-indicator-padding,30px);border-width:1px;border-style:solid;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;margin-bottom:10px}.e-form__indicators__indicator--shape-circle{border-radius:50%}.e-form__indicators__indicator--shape-square{border-radius:0}.e-form__indicators__indicator--shape-rounded{border-radius:5px}.e-form__indicators__indicator--shape-none{border:0}.e-form__indicators__indicator__label{text-align:center}.e-form__indicators__indicator__separator{width:100%;height:var(--e-form-steps-divider-width);background-color:#c2cbd2}.e-form__indicators--type-icon,.e-form__indicators--type-icon_text,.e-form__indicators--type-number,.e-form__indicators--type-number_text{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.e-form__indicators--type-icon .e-form__indicators__indicator__separator,.e-form__indicators--type-icon_text .e-form__indicators__indicator__separator,.e-form__indicators--type-number .e-form__indicators__indicator__separator,.e-form__indicators--type-number_text .e-form__indicators__indicator__separator{margin-top:calc(var(--e-form-steps-indicator-padding, 30px) / 2 - var(--e-form-steps-divider-width, 1px) / 2)}.elementor-field-type-hidden{display:none}.elementor-field-type-html{display:inline-block}.elementor-login .elementor-lost-password,.elementor-login .elementor-remember-me{font-size:.85em}.elementor-field-type-recaptcha_v3 .elementor-field-label{display:none}.elementor-field-type-recaptcha_v3 .grecaptcha-badge{z-index:1}.elementor-button .elementor-form-spinner{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:4;-ms-flex-order:3;order:3}.elementor-form .elementor-button>span{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.elementor-form .elementor-button .elementor-button-text{white-space:normal;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex-positive:0;flex-grow:0}.elementor-form .elementor-button svg{height:auto}.elementor-form .elementor-button .e-font-icon-svg{height:1em}.elementor-select-wrapper .select-caret-down-wrapper{position:absolute;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);-ms-transform:translateY(-50%);transform:translateY(-50%);inset-inline-end:10px;pointer-events:none;font-size:11px}.elementor-select-wrapper .select-caret-down-wrapper svg{display:unset;width:1em;aspect-ratio:unset;fill:currentColor}.elementor-select-wrapper .select-caret-down-wrapper i{font-size:19px;line-height:2}.elementor-select-wrapper.remove-before:before{content:""!important}</style> <form class="elementor-form" method="post" name="Novo formulário">
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="239">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="e828415">
<input type="hidden" name="referer_title" value="testes - EricMmk">
<input type="hidden" name="queried_id" value="239">
<div class="elementor-form-fields-wrapper elementor-labels-above">
<div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-name elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
<input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[name]" id="form-field-name" class="elementor-field elementor-size-md  elementor-field-textual" required="required" aria-required="true"><label for="form-field-name" class="elementor-field-label">
Nome </label>

</div>
<div class="elementor-field-type-email elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-email elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
<input size="1" type="email" name="form_fields[email]" id="form-field-email" class="elementor-field elementor-size-md  elementor-field-textual" required="required" aria-required="true"><label for="form-field-email" class="elementor-field-label">
E-mail </label>

</div>
<div class="elementor-field-type-checkbox elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_d67999d elementor-col-100">
<div class="elementor-field-subgroup  "><span class="elementor-field-option"><input type="checkbox" value="Teste" id="form-field-field_d67999d-0" name="form_fields[field_d67999d]"> <label for="form-field-field_d67999d-0">Teste</label></span></div> </div>
<div class="elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-type-submit elementor-col-100 e-form__buttons">
<button type="submit" class="elementor-button elementor-size-sm">
<span>
<span class=" elementor-button-icon">
</span>
<span class="elementor-button-text">Enviar</span>
</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-f615637 elementor-widget elementor-widget-html" data-id="f615637" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="html.default">
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-field-group input:not([type="checkbox"])').forEach((e) => {
  e.parentNode.insertBefore(e, e.previousElementSibling);
})
</script> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding a snipit to your question that recreates your issue.

Comment: Done, but it's an elementor form widget, so i don't know the code. @dalelandry